# How to install red5 on windows server 2008 with plesk

Tags: php, windows, red5, plesk

Kindly tell me that How to install red5 on windows server 2008 with plesk step by step.

I have read "spatil" Question (i have installed red5 on my server.its running fine on my IP but when i open red5 link (http://myhost:5080) on different IP (or on client side )its not working. please help..).

But I don't know how to install red5 media server on Plesk Windows 2008 server.

regards,
Pankaj

Comment: I would do a +10 if I could. Red5 is poorly documented. Free, but 50% of a philanthropist project.